# Control figure size

Tags: floats

Ever since I started to use LaTeX this issue has been causing me trouble.

When placing an image, like below, if I specify the size just a little bit over what latex wants, it places it on a new page, instead of placing it in context.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=7cm]{Imgs/Image.png}
    \caption{Something pretty}
    \label{fig:ampFas}
\end{figure}
```

This is an issue because the maximum size latex tolerates is too small for most images I use. Specially those with text, like graphs with labeled axes that need to be readable.

How can I force latex to accept the size I want and still place the image within context?

Comment: All float questions needs this to be read https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020#39020

Comment: [ht] will move it to the top of the next page.  [h] will wait until the next \clearpage.

Comment: @John Kormylo I guess I didn't explain myself right. Independently of how I do the placement option, [h] or [t] or [b], latex will place the figure in a new page if the "size" property is to big for it's "liking".

Comment: You could try reducing \textfloatsep, which is the only additional space used by LaTeX.  You can also force a page break in the middle of the previous paragraph.

Comment: Or you could make LaTeX think the figure is smaller than it is and let it stick into the bottom margin.

Comment: Is this of interest? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2282/586